# virualenv on PyCharm from Linux to Windows

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

I am writing because a weird thing is happening on my computer. I have always been using PyCharm professionals on Linux, and I have for each project its own virtual environment. Now I need to move everything on Windows, so I have installed PyCharm and now I want to re-create all the virtual environments for my moved projects. When I do the standard procedure (Settings --> Project Interpreter --> Add Python Interpreter and I select "New Environment" then choose an empty folder) an error occurs:

`Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe" (in directory "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0"): CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied`

What is going wrong?

Comment: Where are you trying to create that venv? In the location somewhere next to the project you have? You can try to run PyCharm as admin (right-click the icon, run as administrator) and it should have access to whatever you want then, but it's a workaround, not finding where problem is.

Comment: I am trying to create the venv into the folder of the project. Anyway, I tried your workaround but the error remains :(

Comment: It is the same location I have been using in Ubuntu. Just another folder

Comment: **SOLVED**: a workaround that works is: create a virtual environment with PowerShell (for me worked to run PowerShell as administrator) by typing ` Python -m venv venvenv`. Then in PyCharm select this interpreter with the standard procedure. Of course in this way you have to install all the packages again, sadly.

Comment: It may be that your directory has strange permissions after being moved between systems. :c As for installing, dump list of installed packages in old env to a file (`pip freeze > requirements.txt` or something like that), then make pip install packages from that list (there's some parameter that allows you to pass a file with package list, but I don't remember it)